# Como detener una clase mientras se ejecuta un formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una clase que llama a un formulario y le pasa ciertas variables por referencia, el formulario cambia las variables según el cliente lo pide y luego esta clase sigue ejecutando mas cosas con estas variables, pero la clase solo ejecuta el método principal de el formulario y no los demás métodos ¿Como puedo hacer para que la clase se detenga hasta que el formulario se cierre? dejo un ejemplo de la clase:

```
public string clase(string a, string b, string c)
{
Formulario x= new Formulario(ref a, ref b, ref c);
x.show();
//necesito que lo de abajo se ejecute luego de que el form de arriba se 
//cierre
if(a==""){return b+c;}
if(b==""){return a+c;}
//Etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero en el formulario que vas a llamar osea en tu caso `Formulario` Crea un método público que se llame `Mostrar()`, luego dentro del mostrar haces un `this.ShowDialog();` este creará una pausa en memoria, luego crea un metodo que se llame cerrar, y ahi asignas todo lo que que vas a darle un retoque final, y al final de ese método llamas a la funcion `Close`, del formularrio, lo que significa que al cerrar el formulario podras consultar todo lo que desees del formulario hijo y se te dará el ultimo estado. te dejo un ejemplo.

Formulario Hijo:

```cs
public string Variable1 = "";
public string Variable2 = "";
public string Variable3 = "";
public string Variable4 = "";

public void Mostrar()
{
 this.ShowDialog();
}

public void Cerrar()
{
  Variable1 = "1";
  Variable2 = "2";
  Variable3 = "3";
  Variable4 = "4";
  this.Close();
}
```

Formulario Padre:

```cs
public void MostrarHijo()
{
  FormularioHijo obj = new FormularioHijo();
  obj.Mostrar();
  Console.WriteLine(obj.Variable1);
  Console.WriteLine(obj.Variable2);
  Console.WriteLine(obj.Variable3);
  Console.WriteLine(obj.Variable4);
}
```

Como podras observar el console write line se ejecuta inmediatamente despues de cerrar el formulario. sl2